# Command to check read/write ratio?

Tags: mysql, monitoring

Is there a command in MySQL that returns the read-to-write ratio of queries so that I'm able to know on what MySQL spends time, and whether the load would lower significantly by splitting data over two servers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the "show status" and check the "Com_%" variables for read/write ratios.

As for splitting the data, you'll have to check the slow query log (Google mysqlsla) and find out if those queries are amicable to being split.

Answer (score 9):

This SQL command will give you an indication as to the read/write ratio:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS WHERE Variable_name = 'Com_insert'
OR Variable_name = 'Com_update'
OR Variable_name = 'Com_select'
OR Variable_name = 'Com_delete';
```

#### 3rd party edit

On one of our servers gave this result

```
  Variable_name    |   Value
   Com_delete      |    6878
   Com_insert      |    5975
   Com_select      |  101061
   Com_update      |    9026
   Bytes_received  | 136301641 <-- added by 3rd party
   Bytes_sent      | 645476511 <-- added by 3rd party
```

I assume that update and insert have different `IO` implications but i combined them like this `Com_insert + Com_update /  Com_select` to get a "write/read" idea. I also use Bytes_received and Bytes_sent - but this might lead to false conclusions since bytes received do not have to lead to a write on disk (for example a long where clause).

```
SELECT (136263935/1000000) AS GB_received
     , (644471797/1000000) AS GB_sent
     , (136263935/644471797) AS Ratio_Received_Sent
     , (6199+9108)/106789 AS Ins_Upd_Select_ratio;
```

This gave this result

```
GB_received |  GB_sent | Ratio_Received_Sent | Ins_Upd_Select_ratio 
    136     |    644   |    0,2114           |     0,1433
```

Comment: @Pyhxx i hope it is ok that i added this example. How would you consider is the Com_update + Com_insert / Com_select a better fit than bytes_received / bytes_sent. Since bytes_received could be informattion for SELECT as well as Insert and Update i assume that this is apples and oranges. Would you add Com_delete to the "read/write" ratio?

Answer (score 5):

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,328920,337142#msg-337142

"SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Com%'. This will give overall counts (since last restart) of each statement type. This will not necessarily tell you whether you are mostly SELECT-bound versus write-bound. You might have a small number in Com_select, but the selects are terribly slow. "